# Gantt chart, duration of activities

Tags: spotfire

I have a data set with several lines of projects, each have start and end dates.

I would like these to be visualized in a gantt chart. For that I have used the scatterplot, but im not able to get the line in from start to end date.

Am I missing something?

Data looks similar to this:

[image]

I have tried this, but it doesn't solve my issue:
https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfirer-tipstricks-how-create-gantt-chart-visualization

I have tried to make a calculated column with days of duration along with playing with the line connection function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way to do this is massage your data such that you have the Start and End dates in a single column. You can accomplish this by unpivoting the data table (pass through project and transform start and end date).

After that, you can create a scatter plot with the new table, putting the newly created value column on the X axis and the project on the Y axis.

Comment: Hi, this is a good point. I noticed this in a thread also, but I hoped I was able to do it more simple. Would you think I could do this in a calculated column like =Start date, End Date?

Comment: Not in any way I can think of!